# Problems with paste url into the JFile Chooser and hit enter

Tags: java, swing, url, jfilechooser

I'm using `JFileChooser` with Swing to get the input files. In the file open window, people will copy and paste the url into the "File Name:" and hit enter, then you will see all the files under that url folder. It was all working, but when you include the http: in that url, the file open window would close when hit enter, without letting you choose the files under that url folder and the address is not returned by the  `showOpenDialog` method correctly.

I don't know what "http:" in the url will do to the `JFileChooser`, but my goal is to let the `JFileChooser` act like there is no "http:" in the url and display the spreadsheet file under that url folder.

Below is the code I used for the JFileChooser:

```
 fc = new JFileChooser();
 FileFilter xlsxExcelType = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx)", "xlsx");
 fc.addChoosableFileFilter(xlsExcelType);
 fc.addChoosableFileFilter(xlsxExcelType);
 fc.setFileFilter(xlsExcelType);
 fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
 int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(CampaignTestFrame.this);
```

Comment: *"..under that url folder"*  I've heard of folders (or in a non GUI sense, directories) and also of URLs, but I've never heard of an 'URL folder'.  What is that?

Comment: `File` and `JFileChooser` are meant to access a local file system. You can't access files over http with this basic API.   Also, what does your server respond when you query the URL you mention? (e.g. what do you see in the browser when you type the URL?)